# How to display the mean (in text) for a histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I want to add the mean value. `geom_text(aes(mean(rnorm))` and `geom_label(aes(mean(rnorm))` did not do the job.

The mean should be displayed for each of the species (sp)

```
set.seed(111)
rand.data <- rnorm(1000,5,1)
sp <- rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each =250)
rand.df <- data.frame(rand.data,sp)

rand.df$sp <- as.factor(rand.df$sp)

ggplot(rand.df, aes(x=rand.data), color = sp) + geom_histogram() +
  theme_classic() + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(rand.data)), color="blue", linetype="dashed", size=1) + facet_grid(.~sp)
```

[image]

Edit: I also notice that the geom_vline() as written here does not show the means broken down by sp, but rather displays the overall mean

```
rand.df %>% 
  group_by(sp)%>% 
  dplyr::summarise(rand.df.mean = mean(rand.data))
```

Comment: You need to add a y to the aesthetic mapping

Comment: @AllanCameron A) I have edited the question B) How can I add a y to a histogram plot.

Comment: I get `Error in set(set.seed) : could not find function "set"` (or, with `data.table` loaded, I see `Error in set(set.seed) : argument "j" is missing, with no default`), are you trying to set the random seed for reprex? (1) It's use is `set.seed(42)` (or some number), and (2) that really only does us any good if we see actual results from your randomness: you're showing neither the random data nor the image produced by it (nor what you _expect_ the image to look like, with real values somehow identified).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a faceted alternative:

```r
library(dplyr)
means <- rand.df %>%
  group_by(sp) %>%
  summarize(rand.mean = round(mean(rand.data), 2))
ggplot(rand.df, aes(x=rand.data)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(color = sp)) +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = rand.mean), data = means, color="blue", linetype="dashed", linewidth=1) +
  geom_label(aes(x = rand.mean, label = rand.mean), y = Inf, data = means, vjust = 1.5) +
  facet_grid(.~sp)
```

[image: ggplot2 with colored and labeled histograms]

Notes:

- `ggplot2` prefers `linewidth=` to `size=` for lines
- your initial use of `color=sp` was outside the `aes(.)`, so it was interpreted as a static (non-varying); moving it inside the `aes` makes it do what I think you intended; in fact, I moved it within the `geom_histogram` since it would otherwise apply to all geoms (you can do that if you want)
- I chose `color=` for the histograms, you may also prefer `fill=sp` instead or in addition (I think `fill=` makes more sense)